# Better words for "buff" and "debuff"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I have an RPG environment and I'm looking for words that sound better than "buff" for positive modifier and "debuff" for negative modifier. I simply don't like the words but I'm having a hard time finding more appropriate words.

Comment: Which sense of _buff_ are you using? The color, the polish, or the muscles? And _RPG_ is likely to be less informative in a non-RPG environment, so better to spend a few bits on a fuller context. Especially on what you expect the verb _'to buff'_ to mean. But you gotta be clear if you want clear answers.

Comment: I think *buff* is sufficiently commonly used in RPGs to be absolutely clear to any (non-naïve) player.

Comment: @JohnLawler he's using the sense in which it's normally used in [RPG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_video_game)s.

Comment: IMO there is still a lot of context missing.

Where exactly are these words to show up? On a actions panel? In the middle of a battle? Are you space limited? You don't like buff and debuff (which are standard in RPG games) for any special reason? I'd suggest upgrade/downgrade as jwpat suggested, but it will eventually depend on the final context. Is this RPG from the middle ages or is it maybe a futuristic one?

Comment: As a totally naive non-player, I have no idea how those words are used in RPGs (and the Wikipedia article didn't enlighten me). Anyone able to clarify?

Comment: @onomatomaniak: buff is used for instance when some kind of positive spell/action is done on a player. For instance I can "cast a buff on you" (or "buff you) by casting a spell that increases your strenght/intelligence/etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Buff/debuff* seems like a good pair of words for the enhance/downgrade contrast that the terms stand for in role-playing games, and they probably are well understood in that environment.  You might consider *unbuff* in place of *debuff*.  Some other possible or impossible pairings: *tune/detune, amplify/attenuate, raise/lower, boost/unboost, trim/pare, furbish/disfurbish, augment/deduct, add on/strip, upgrade/downgrade, enhance/detract*.

Comment: Wow thanks for this reply. I really like AMP, and I might use it as another term for the game. I'm already using boost as another term (hopefully boost and buff wont be confusing). Enhance and upgrade are good ones too. Overall this answer was very useful to me, and I think I'm gonna stick with Buff because you're right, they are well known. I'm just picky xD.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Augment and Debilitate.  It's hard to find words that cover all bonuses and penalties, but I think these do so.

Answer (score 1):

I, myself have tried the same, but the most important part is theme of your status effect. If your buffs/debuffs are all religious, it could be blessing/curse. But if they are all magic, it could be enchant/jinx. For theme-neutral ones, I'd suggest boon/bane or boon/condition (GW2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to introduce new terms in the sense of improving sth. ('positive modifier') and its converse, in place of *buff* | *debuff*, you could consider using the pair:

> **shine** | **matte**

*Shine* v. is analogous to *buff*. *Matte* conveys the opposite meaning.

Comment: Thank you. These are great words IMO but they don't fit the context right. If they did I would surely use them.

Answer (score 0):

Best alternative I've seen is from ArenaNet and their Guild Wars series. "Boons" and "Conditions".

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post awhile back and wanted to leave my own little something for future readers. In the internal engine that the game Everquest and Everquest 2 uses, the enumerations that signify buffs is labeled as "Beneficial" effects, and Debuffs are internally referred to as "Detrimental" effects. Buff and debuff is just a slang word used by the community of players.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not an RPG player, but my first instinct is to agree with you that "buff" is a poor choice of word insofar as it doesn't fit in with any of the story genres I see RPGers play in. "Debuff" isn't in my vocabulary.

The most generic, commonly used word I can think of is "enhance", and I suggest you consult a thesaurus for its synonyms.

A suitable opposite might be "degrade" or "diminish", and again, I suggest you consult a thesaurus.